# Errant Facebook SDK Batch request

Tags: javascript, facebook, batch-processing, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a Facebook SDK Batch, and one of the requests is returning the following error:

```
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100
}
```

Here's the Batch:

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
  batch: [
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'user',
      relative_url : '/me'
    },
    { 
      method: 'GET', 
      name : 'post-ids',
      relative_url: '/group-id/feed?fields=id',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    { 
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-data',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}&fields=id,actions,application,from,to,message,message_tags,with_tags,picture,place,properties,source,status_type,link,description,caption,attachments,object_id,type,created_time,updated_time,likes.summary(1),comments.summary(1)',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-user-info',
      relative_url : '/{result=post-data:$.data.*.from.id}/',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-likes',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}/likes?limit=5000',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    },
    {
      method : 'GET',
      name : 'post-comments',
      relative_url : '?ids={result=post-ids:$.data.*.id}/comments?fields=id,actions,application,from,to,message,message_tags,with_tags,picture,place,properties,source,status_type,link,description,caption,attachments,object_id,type,created_time,updated_time,likes.summary(1)&limit=5000',
      omit_response_on_success : false
    }
  ]
}, function (response) {
```

The fourth request, name `post-user-info` is the errant request. Basically, for each post, I want to get the information (profile picture in particular) about the user that created the post. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you are using the Field Expansion syntax already, but only partially – why not use it to get the profile pic as well? Maybe then you don’t need to do batch requests any more at all … `me/feed?fields=from{picture}` should get you the profile pictures straight away.

Comment: @CBroe this is all for a group feed (I just updated to reflect that), so if I understand it all correctly, `me/feed` would show me posts from the logged in user. correct?

Comment: Yeah well then replace `me` with the group id …

Comment: @CBroe Ok, so I just added `{id,name,picture}` to the `from` field in my `post`data` call above, but I'm not receiving all pictures. Could that have something to do with privacy or do you think that might be something I need to figure out?

Comment: Might be privacy-related, yes. API version 2 introduced a lot stricter handling of such things.